# C++ set std::map value to pointer of struct instance

Tags: c++, pointers, stdmap

I have multiple devices, each of these has its own set of functions, each with different values and different variable types. I am trying to create a dataset that stores these variables in a simple way to access them while dynamically adding or removing these devices.

My idea was to create a class that holds the device info, with a struct that can be used for the different functions. To easily access the devices and functions, the device/function name would be stored in a map as the key and the pointer to the instance of the class/struct would be stored as the value of that key. For the devices map, this worked fine. However, for the functions map, inside the class, I can't seem to get it to work. So...

1) What is the proper way of placing the struct pointer into the map?

2) Is it a good idea to place a struct in a class?

3) I am fairly new to C++ so is there a better STL or method of doing this?

> This clip of code is located in an .hpp file

```
std::map<std::string, device*> devices;
class device {
private:
    //Device info
    std::string devName;
    size_t devId;
    char state;

    std::map<std::string, struct func *func> functions; //---Error

    //Setup for multiple functions
    struct func{
        //Functions info
        std::string funcName;
        size_t funcId;
        char funcType;

    };

public:
//Functions to get device and function values
```

I run this code on Linux (Ubuntu 19.04), and I use Visual Studio Code as my IDE. The error it gives me is:

> expected a '>' where *func is.

Comment: Move the definition of `struct funct` above your `functions` map. Or put it in a .h file and include it where needed.

Comment: ... or forward declare it.  It looks like `device` was forward declared so this should work the same way.

Comment: The template parameters need to be types. `struct func` is a type. `struct func *` is a type too, but `struct func * func` is not a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I was able to figure it out.

```
std::map<std::string, device*> devices;
class device {
private:
   //Device info
   std::string devName;
   size_t devId;
   char state;

   //Setup for multiple functions
   struct func{
       //Functions info
       std::string funcName;
       size_t funcId;
       char funcType;
   };

   //Map of funcution Id's to pointers of function objects
   std::map <id, func*> functions;

  public:
  //Functions to get device and function values
```

It was a forward declaration error.